# Start process in new session to be able to kill all tree at once

Tags: linux, session, puppet, kill, process-group

There is a Linux-oriented Python program that is launching Puppet subprocess. Puppet is a configuration management software and while executing it launches many subprocesses (yum, curl, custom scripts etc.) Python code has a watchdog that kills puppet subprocess if it is running too long. In a current version it uses os.kill to do that.
The problem is that when puppet process is killed on timeout, it's orphaned children are attached to "init" and keep running. Typically these children are an initial cause of a timeout.

**The first attempt** was killing the entire process group (os.killpg). But kill call fails with OSError(3, 'No such process'). After studying process management docs I understood that it does not work because puppet itself launches ruby process in a separate process group. Also, process group is not inherited by children, so os.killpg would not help anyway. Yes, POSIX allows to set PGID of children with some limitations, but it requires iterative monitoring of new subprocesses and looks like a hack in my case.

**Next attempt** was running Puppet in a separate shell ("sh -c")/"su" environment/setsid (in various combinations). The desired result is to start this process (and children) in a new session. I expect that it will allow to emulate something like remote ssh connection disconnect: sending SIGHUP to session leader, eg puppet process, will send SIGHUP to an entire tree of children. So I will be able to kill the entire tree. Experiments with running puppet through remote SSH connection show that this approach seems to work: all processes die after terminal disconnect. I have not achieved this behaviour from Python yet. **Is this approach correct, am I missing something or it's an ugly hack?**

**One more approach** I see is to send SIGSTOP to every process in tree (iterating while there is at least one running process in a tree to avoid race conditions), and then kill every process individually. This approach will work, but looks not too elegant.

Problem is not related to Python code, it also reproduces when running "puppet apply" from a console and sending signals using the "kill" command.

Yes, I know that Puppet has a "timeout" keyword for the described purpose, but I am looking for a more general solution, applicable not only to Puppet, but to any fruitful subprocess.